# Navbar gone after search button click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a searching page that contains an input, a button, and will render products when search is matched. After clicking the search button, my navbar is gone but other functions still run well as far as I checked. Can anyone point what seems to be the problem?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {productSearch } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SearchResult extends Component {

onSearchBtnClick=()=>{
    this.props.productSearch(this.refs.search.value)
}

selectedProduct(id){
    cookies.set('SelectedProduct', id, { path: '/' });
}

renderItemList(){
    // global state is mapped here
}
render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1> SEARCH  PAGE</h1>
            <span>
                <input type='text' ref='search' placeholder='Search Product'/>
                <input type='button' value='Search' onClick={this.onSearchBtnClick}/>
            </span>
            <div>
                {this.renderItemList()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const searchResult = state.searchResult
    return {searchResult};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {productSearch})(SearchResult);
```

Comment: Was there any error in console?

Comment: nothing about any particular function in this component.